# Android studio Gradle sync failed

Tags: java, android

I just created a new project on Android studio and it isn't building successfully with the error, Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroid Test/compileClasspath': Could not resolve javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2. 
And also my MainActivity.java is giving an error Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Comment: Can you post your Gradle files?

Comment: @Christopher Do you mean the build.gradle?

Comment: Yes. Both please (global and app's build.gradle)

Comment: use mavenCentral() instead jcenter() in gradle file

Comment: @YasharPanahi How? 
I should delete jcenter() in the gradle code that appears?

Comment: No u won't loose anything....at the time of installation of Android studio it will be asking to import previous projects and settings....so don't worry about losing your projects...hope u got it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File>Invalidate caches/Restart and choose invalidate and restart.